# smoother curves in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I make a smoother parabola in `pgfplots`?

The following code produces a parabola with jagged edges:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
\begin{axis}[
axis x line=bottom, 
axis y line=left, 
xmax=250, 
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={}, 
tick style={color=white}, 
xticklabels={,,}, yticklabels={,,}, 
extra y ticks={1}, 
extra y tick style={yticklabel={$c$},yticklabel style={yshift=0ex,anchor=east}},
x label style={at={(axis description cs:1.05,0.14)},anchor=north}
]
    \addplot[domain=0:240, black, thick] {0.01*(6*x - 0.025*x^2)};
    \addplot[domain=0:240, red, thick] {1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: You can add `smooth` as an option to `addplot`.

Comment: or you can specifically set the number of samples.

Comment: @TeXnician adding `smooth` works, thanks!

Comment: @daleif I thought I set the samples with `domain=0:240`. Is that false?

Comment: No, you specified the domain, the number of samples is independent (you could even have domain 0:1, but specify 1000 samples).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a smooth plot you should specify the `smooth` option for `\addplot`. This will try to *guess* (using bezier curves) the right correction for the plot and connect the samples without those edges.

Another (and maybe better) approach would be to increase the number of samples (key `samples`) which would result in more data (not altered data) which could be used to plot the function. That also means that you would have a smoother plot. You can even combine both keys.

Comment: also `smooth` alters the data . it doesn't interpolat it uses bezier curves instead so the better option is to increase the samples

Comment: @percusse I tried to say that by using the word "guess". But I'll make the post more precise.

Comment: I mean there is no guessing involved. It blindly distors the data. `smooth` is just a visual pleasing solution. It should only be used for rough visualizations especially if the data points are close to each other